# Pyspark TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable while using OneHotEncoder in Spark MLlib

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am new to pyspark and Apache Spark machine learning library. I am trying to apply OneHotEncoder for several categorical columns in Spark MLlib.
I follow the programming guide.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder

First I used stringIndexer, it works.

```
stringIndexer = StringIndexer(
    inputCols=[categoricalCol for categoricalCol in categoricalColumns],
    outputCols=[categoricalCol + "_index" for categoricalCol in categoricalColumns]
)
mod_si = stringIndexer.fit(spark_df)
indexed_si = mod_si.transform(spark_df)
```

categoricalColumns is list of my categorical columns in dataset.

then OneHotEncoder;

```
encoder = OneHotEncoder(
    inputCols=[indexer.getOutputCol() for indexer in indexed_si],
    outputCols=["_encoded".format(indexer.getOutputCol()) for indexer in indexed_si]
)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Any help is appreciated. I can't go forward next steps without solving this problem.
Thank you very much.

Comment: indexed_si is a dataframe, and indexer is a column. You can't call getOutputCol() on a column. Consult the docs for examples on how to use the encoders properly. https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.ml.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I found the solution.